# Is true arithmetic + $\lnot Con (TA)$ consistent?

Tags: lo.logic

Is the theory $TA+\lnot Con(TA)$ consistent?

In particular, for every $TA \vdash \phi$, we take as an axiom $\phi$, and $TA \vdash \phi$. We also assert $TA \vdash 0 = 1$. We call this theory $TA + \lnot Con(TA)$.

Note that the theory we are talking about does *not* include the statement that $TA$ is true (i.e. $TA \vdash \phi \iff \phi$). The theory can only see what $TA$ implies, and that $TA$ is a theory of first order arithmetic.

Is this theory consistent?

Note: TA + $\lnot Con(TA)$ is not a theory in the language of arithmetic. We are adjoining a symbol for $TA \vdash$ to the language (as an unary predicate on godel codes). You can also interpret it as a weak set theory.

---

---

**EDIT: This is an attempt by someone other than the OP to describe the theory in question in a clearer way; this should not be taken as fully accurate until the OP weighs in.**

Let $T_0$ be the theory, in the language of arithmetic together with a new unary predicate symbol $P$, consisting of the following axioms:

- Each $\varphi\in $ TA.
- Each sentence of the form "$P(n)$" for $n$ the Godel number of a sentence in TA.
- $P(\ulcorner 0=1\urcorner)$.

This is (I believe) the theory the OP describes.

Meanwhile, here are some sentences which are **not** in our theory *(I'm explicitly mentioning them to make it clear that the above really is a complete description of the OP's theory in question)*:

- **Internal modus ponens (IMP)**: The sentence $$\forall x, y[P(x)\wedge P(implies(x, y)\implies P(y)].$$ 
  Here "$implies$" is an abbreviation for the usual primitive recursive binary function given by $(\ulcorner p\urcorner, \ulcorner q\urcorner)\mapsto \ulcorner p\implies q\urcorner$. *The point is that we could write this as an axiom scheme, ranging over all actual Godel numbers of appropriate sentences, but we can actually just get it with a single sentence. This isn't a big deal, and if one prefers one can use the scheme version without any impact here.*
- **Reflection (R)**: the scheme "$P(\ulcorner \varphi\urcorner)\implies\varphi$" for arithmetic $\varphi$.
- **Completeness (C)**: the scheme "$\varphi\implies P(\ulcorner\varphi\urcorner)$" for arithmetic $\varphi$.

Comment: How do you express $\neg Con(TA)$ in the language of arithmetic? Or what language do you express your theory in?

Comment: @Wojowu Arithmetic+a symbol for $TA$ and $\vdash$.

Comment: Okay then. How do you express $\neg Con(TA)$ in the language of arithmetic with this adjoined symbol?

Comment: @Wojowu $TA \vdash 0=1$ (or rather $TA \vdash \text{godel code of 
 }0=1$).

Comment: What are $TA$ and $\vdash$ in this language? Constants, relations, functions? I can't figure how in either of the cases $TA\vdash 0=1$ is a well-formed formula

Comment: @Wojowu $TA$ is a constant symbol, and $\vdash$ is a binary relation.

Comment: If $TA$ is a constant symbol, then it ought to be interpreted as some natural number. I don't think this is what you intend.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the symbol for $TA$ is extraneous: you really just want a unary relation symbol $P$ and axioms of the form $P(n)$ whenever $n$ is a Godel number of a sentence of true arithmetic, *or* the Godel number of "$0=1$." I think it will be easier to precisely define your object of study in this more limited language. Is there any real reason to include a constant symbol (which you'll need to think of as representing some natural number)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Okay, I edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: @PyRulez I think your question does a better job of describing the theory in question, but is still not completely clear; may I add a "below-the-fold" part to give a description of the theory along the lines suggested in my answer?

Comment: @NoahSchweber sure

Comment: @PyRulez I've made an edit; please delete it, preserve it, alter it, or tell me to do one of those three as you will.

Comment: @NoahSchweber good except I never intended there to be reflection. I've fixed it.

Comment: @PyRulez I only mentioned reflection as something explicitly *not* part of the theory (see "meanwhile ...") - I thought it was relevant to mention natural properties the theory didn't have.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh whoops, misread. One property you forgot to mention is that it knows that $TA$ is a first-order theory of arithmetic (which implies deduction rules (including IMP) hold). It's not a big deal, since the question turned out to be pretty bad anyways, but just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: @PyRulez "it knows that TA is a first-order theory of arithmetic" What does that mean, exactly? (More to the point, what axioms do you add to $T_0$ to ensure this?)

Comment: @NoahSchweber well, the fact that it follows all deduction rules of first order logic. They are added as axioms.

Comment: @PyRulez But that needs to be built in via additional axioms governing the behavior of $P$ (this is exactly what IMP is). On the face of it, $P$ just describes some set of natural numbers; saying that $P(n)$ holds whenever $n$ is a Godel number of true arithmetic doesn't give $P$ the modus ponens property.

Comment: Put it another way, suppose I told you I have a set $S$ of sentences containing every sentence of TA and also containing $0=1$. You would need additional information about $S$ to conclude that it contains, say, $1=2$; all you know is that $0=1$ and $(0=1)\implies (1=2)$ are in $S$, but you don't have any "global" facts about $S$ yet.

Comment: @NoahSchweber sorry, I forgot to specify that "$TA$ is a first order arithmetic" *is* an axiom (or axiom schema, if needed).

Comment: @PyRulez What exactly does "$TA$ is a first order arithmetic" mean? I think you mean that you're adding axioms corresponding to the usual logical inference rules (such as IMP, and $(P(m)\wedge P(n))\implies P(and(m, n))$, and so on) - is that correct?

Comment: @NoahSchweber yes

Comment: @PyRulez Ah, ok. Note that TA is strong enough that we actually only need IMP and "internal and-introduction" IAI (the other rule in my previous comment) to get the desired closure properties, since whenever a finite set of sentences of arithmetic $\Delta$ proves a sentence of arithmetic $\psi$ we have $(\bigwedge\Delta)\implies\psi$ in TA. May I edit my edit to bring IMP and IAI in as axioms of your theory $T_0$?

Comment: Since I find the question very interesting I feel obliged to confess that I downvoted it :D

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე it probably would've been better for math.se.

Comment: IAI follows from modus ponens.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Oh yes quite right. (To the OP, and using obvious abbreviations: suppose we have $P(p)$ and $P(q)$. Well, in TA we have $P(p\implies (q\implies p\wedge q))$. By IMP we get $P(q\implies p\wedge q)$ and then by IMP again we get $P(p\wedge q)$.)

Answer (score 8):

Usually we use the notation $\newcommand\TA{\text{TA}}\TA$ to denote the theory of *true arithmetic*, meaning the theory of the standard model of arithmetic $\langle\mathbb{N},+,\cdot,0,1,<\rangle$ in the usual language of arithmetic, or in other words, the collection of all sentences that are true in that structure.

Tarski's theorem on the non-definability of truth, however,  tells us that the set of Gödel codes of assertions in $\TA$ is not arithmetically definable. It follows that we cannot express $\text{Con}(\TA)$ directly in the language of arithmetic, in the way that we are able to express $\text{Con}(\text{PA})$ or $\text{Con}(T)$ for other arithmetically definable theories $T$.

For this reason, with the ordinary usage of $\text{Con}$, there is no such assertion as $\text{Con}(\TA)$, and it is not sensible to write such things as $\TA+\neg\text{Con}(\TA)$.

If one wants truly to refer to the consistency of $\TA$, one must therefore  take far more care in the details of the formalization, to make it clear exactly how it is that one will try to refer to the consistency of this theory and what it is that is meant. I don't see that you have really done that extra work sufficiently in your question, and I think that this is the reason your question has not had a positive reception.

Meanwhile, let me point you toward the Mostowski reflection theorem, which I believe can be taken as a kind of negative answer to a version of the question that one might have asked.

Namely, it is not difficult to see that for any standard natural number $n$, one can write down a definition of a $\Sigma_n$ truth predicate $\text{Tr}_n$, and $\newcommand\PA{\text{PA}}\PA$ proves that indeed this definition fulfills the Tarskian recursion for all $\Sigma_n$ formulas. Thus, $\text{Tr}_n$ is an arithmetically definable predicate referring to the $\Sigma_n$ fragment of true arithmetic. This is an approximation to $\TA$.

**Theorem.**(Mostowski reflection theorem) For any standard natural number $n$, the theory $\PA$ proves $\text{Con}(\text{Tr}_n)$.

See *Mostowski, A.*, [**On models of axiomatic systems**](https://eudml.org/doc/213259), Fundam. Math. 39, 133-158 (1953). [ZBL0053.20102](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0053.20102).

This theorem can be seen as a stronger version of the often mentioned fact that $\PA$ proves the consistency of all of its particular finite subtheories. In particular, this implies that $\PA$ is not finitely axiomatizable.

Comment: A small quibble re your fourth paragraph: I think the OP has clearly after edit stated their theory (the key point being the note at the end of the question - which I think really should be the body of the question), but it's too weak to do what they want and becomes inconsistent once augmented in the obvious way as per my answer.

Comment: Yes, they have stated a theory, but (in part for the reasons that you point out), it is inadequate. I believe that the Mostowski reflection theorem may be much closer to what the OP was searching, since $\text{Tr}_n$ is simply the $\Sigma_n$ fragment of $\TA$, and it is arithmetically definable, so $\text{Con}(\text{Tr}_n)$ makes sense.

Comment: Probably there is a more helpful reference, and I'd appreciate it if the proof theorists could provide one.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Mostowski's theorem was later proved in more generality (but with pretty much the same type of reasoning) by Montague in his 1958 dissertation. It states that any first order theory that incorporates induction (over the natural numbers) and has a modicum of sequence coding  [such as extensions of  PA, Zermelo set theory, and Kelley-Morse class theory, for example] is able to prove the consistency of each finitely axiomatizable subtheory of itself.   This can be found, e.g., in the Hajek and Pudlak "bible "Metamathematics of First-order Arithmetic".

Comment: Thanks, Ali. That statement, however, does not seem directly to generalized the statement I made, since $\Sigma_n$ truth is not a finitely axiomatizable fragment of PA. Is there a tighter connection? What is the strongest version of the result?

Comment: Do you mind taking a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2456919/21820)? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I think you haven't written what you want to.

At present your theory has a simple model: it's the expansion of standard arithmetic by interpreting $P$ as exactly the set of Godel numbers of sentences of true arithmetic and of "$0=1$."

One thing missing from this is an appropriate "deduction theorem" axiom - you don't have a rule saying "$P(p), P(p\implies q)\implies P(q)$" or similar (conflating sentences and their Godel numbers). Adding this lets us prove "$\forall x(P(x))$" since "$0=1\implies p$" is in TA for every sentence $p$.

However, we **still** have a consistent theory! Namely, if $\mathcal{M}$ is any model of TA then the expansion of $\mathcal{M}$ by interpreting $P$ as the set of all natural numbers gives  a model of this stronger theory. This reflects the really important problem with the theory you've described: you don't have any kind of **reflection**. That is, just knowing "$P(n)$" doesn't let you conclude anything about arithmetic, and so there's no interaction between the two parts of the theory.

In order to get your "internal version" of TA to work properly, the most natural thing to add is the reflection scheme $$P(\ulcorner p\urcorner)\implies p$$ as $p$ ranges through the sentences of true arithmetic. However, at this point we get an immediate contradiction since $P(\ulcorner 0=1\urcorner)$ and the reflection scheme gives $0=1$. On the other hand, without a reflection scheme there's no connection between $P$ and truth in the model, so no reason to believe that anything weird is happening.

---

EDIT: In the language of my edit to the OP, here is a summary of the situation:

- $T_0$ is consistent: for example, the natural numbers together with $P$ interpreted as the whole universe satisfies $T_0$ *(note that no axiom in $T_0$ implies $\exists x(\neg P(x))$)*.
- $T_0$ + C + IMP is also consistent: the model above is also a model of this theory (again, because neither C nor IMP provide any *negative* facts about $P$).
- $T_0$ + R is inconsistent. Indeed, the tiny subtheory R$_{0=1}$ + $P(\ulcorner 0=1 \urcorner)$ + $\neg 0=1$ is inconsistent (where "R$_\varphi$" denotes the instance of reflection for $\varphi$).

The first bulletpoint means that the answer to your question as asked *(assuming I've interpreted it correctly)* is "yes," but the example model indicates that $T_0$ probably isn't what you actually want; meanwhile, the third bulletpoint suggests that the answer to the question I think you want to ask is "no." The second bulletpoint has no direct relevance, I just think it's worth mentioning in the context of considering theories like this.

Comment: "The theory can only see what TA implies, and that TA is **a theory of first order arithmetic**." That implies that TA satisfies modus ponens.

Comment: Basically, $TA + \lnot Con (TA)$ sees a theory, and sees that it is first order arithmetic, and that implies certain statements. It does not know that it is "true".

Comment: @PyRulez The fact that TA satisfies modus ponens has nothing to do with it. Remember that we're working with an abstract *unary predicate symbol* here, and there's no reason to believe $P(p)\wedge P(p\implies q)\implies q$. You can see this directly by noting that the structure of standard arithmetic augmented by interpreting $P$ as the set of Godel numbers of sentences in TA or of $0=1$ satisfies your theory. That is, you need to add something to your theory to make it satisfy the intuitive principles you want it to.

Comment: I think it will be helpful to you to drop the symbol "$TA\vdash$" from your language, and write it in terms of a new, arbitrary unary predicate symbol "$P$" - this will prevent conflation of internal and external reasoning.

Comment: Alternative "fix" is to not only add $P(n)$ for codes of true sentences, but also $\neg P(n)$ for codes of false sentences. But then adding $P(\ulcorner 0=1\urcorner)$ leads to contradiction immediately.

Comment: @PyRulez This is super late, but I just noticed a serious typo in my commet above: it should read: $${}{}$$" . . . There's no reason to believe $P(\ulcorner p\urcorner)\wedge P(\ulcorner p\implies q\urcorner)\implies P(\ulcorner q\urcorner)$. . . ." $${}{}$$ Omitting the "$\ulcorner$$\cdot$$\urcorner$s" isn't too bad, since they're clear from context, but the last "$P$" is quite important.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on what everyone else is already saying: if T is an effective (i.e. recursively enumerable) arithmetic theory, then Con(T) is basically an arithmetic sentence asserting that the Turing machine enumerating the theorems of T never generates the sentence "0=1".  T's recursive enumerability in turn means (by definition) that a finite sized Turing machine *exists* that generates those theorems.  And Gödel brilliantly showed that this statement (about the Turing machine not generating 0=1, translated from computability jargon) can be encoded as an arithmetic sentence.

Gödel's incompleteness theorem can be seen as proving that True Arithmetic (TA) is not recursively enumerable (since if it was, it would be incomplete, and thus wouldn't be TA). That means there can be no such sentence asserting TA's consistency (since it would have to encode a Turing machine that generates all of TA's sentences, but by incompleteness, there is no such machine).

So the problem is not just that "TA + ¬Con(TA) is not a theory in the language of arithmetic".  It's that Con(TA) and ¬Con(TA) aren't even *sentences* in the language of arithmetic.

That's why your question doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: -1. This isn't what the OP is confused about: they're aware of Tarski's undefinability theorem, and they're asking about a situation where instead we add a predicate symbol intended to "represent" TA and some axioms governing its behavior. The undefinability of TA in the language of arithmetic is *not* the issue here.